# Merge [encoder] → [video-encoding]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Questions currently tagged under [encoder](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/encoder) (x8) all are about [video-encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-encoding), and therefore should be merged.

Comment: While that might be true, it's not an often used tag. How'd I tag something about e.g. LAME?

Comment: True that. Maybe we should just leave it. `[audio-encoding]` would make sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have retagged all the questions. The tag will disappear from the system soon (I think), so it shouldn't be an issue now.

Comment: … but we still need the synonym :)

Comment: @slhck Indeed we do, but this is half a solution to start :)

Comment: @slhck hope you know synonym created [isn't restricted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/133693) to Mods ;)

Comment: @slhck There's even a [bronze badge](http://superuser.com/badges/115/synonymizer) for it, so it's really basic use of the site ;-)

Comment: @Sathya Thinking about it we should maybe leave that tag alone. Can you `[status-completed]` this?

Comment: @DanielBeck It's a bronze badge awarded to 27 users, I don't call that basic use :P Also, scroll through [that list](http://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest), I don't think any "normal" user really does anything here, at least on SU.